# Dynamic controllers bound from scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to create "components" dynamically, based on data received from my backend. The goal is to display parts of my application, without using server side templating : instead of displaying components server-side, the server sends JSON data containing which components should be displayed.

Here is what I've got so far :

```js
var module = angular.module('testApp', []);

module.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test 1";
}])
.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test 2";
}])
.controller('ComponentsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    // this is JSON returned by backend
    $scope.components = [{
        name: "Wd1",
        controller: "Ctrl1",
    }, {
        name: "Wd2",
        controller: "Ctrl2",
    }];

    $scope.test = "test";
}]);
```

And my view :

```html
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="ComponentsController">
        <div ng-repeat="component in components">
            <p>{{component.name}} - {{component.controller}}</p>
        </div>

        <div ng-repeat="component in components">
            <p ng-controller="component.controller">{{test}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I get the following error :

> Error: Argument 'component.controller' is not a function, got string

I tried to write a directive, assigning controller names during compile, but as it is done during compile, it doesn't work with binding...

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mathieu/bTQA5/

Comment: Indeed, the first version of the question used simple functions as controllers. However this was an oversimplification of my use case. I need to user controller names, as the data will be fetched from my backend, in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following directive which will insert a controller based on a name:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', []);

module
.directive('dynamicController', ['$controller', function($controller) {
    return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                var locals = {
                    $scope: scope,
                    $element: element,
                    $attrs: attrs
                };

                element.data('$Controller', $controller(scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicController), locals));                       
            }
        };
    }
])
```

```js
var module = angular.module('testApp', []);

module
  .directive('dynamicController', ['$controller',
    function($controller) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

          var locals = {
            $scope: scope,
            $element: element,
            $attrs: attrs
          };

          element.data('$Controller', $controller(scope.$eval(attrs.dynamicController), locals));
        }
      };
    }
  ])

.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = "test 1";
    }
  ])
  .controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.test = "test 2";
    }
  ])
  .controller('ComponentsController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.components = [{
        name: "Wd1",
        controller: "Ctrl1",
      }, {
        name: "Wd2",
        controller: "Ctrl2",
      }];

      $scope.test = "test";
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="ComponentsController">
    <div ng-repeat="component in components" dynamic-controller="component.controller">
      <p><span>{{test}}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the functions to the data in scope:

```js
function ComponentsController($scope) {

    $scope.Ctrl1 = function () {
        $scope.test = "test 1";
    }

    $scope.Ctrl2 = function () {
        $scope.test = "test 2";
    }

    $scope.components = [{
        name: "Wd1",
        controller: $scope.Ctrl1
    }, {
        name: "Wd2",
        controller: $scope.Ctrl2
    }];

    $scope.test = "test";
}
```

And here's the [**updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTQA5/3/).

Note that there's still a logical issue here; The `{{ test }}` binding will be evaluated as soon as the controller does, so the resulted text (on every binding) will be the last evaluation made, i.e. *"Test 2"*, in our case.

You may want to tie logic to handlers instead, e.g. `ng-click`, to be executed on demand:

```html
<div ng-repeat="component in components">
    <button ng-controller="component.controller" 
            ng-click="component.controller()">
        Call {{ component.name }} controller
    </button>
</div>
```

And here it is [**demonstrated live as well**](http://jsfiddle.net/bTQA5/7/).

---

*This answer is based on the first version of this question, which included the following code:*

```js
function ComponentsController($scope) {
    $scope.components = [{
        name: "Wd1",
        controller: "Ctrl1",
    }, {
        name: "Wd2",
        controller: "Ctrl2",
    }];

    $scope.test = "test";
}

function Ctrl1($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test 1";
}

function Ctrl2($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test 2";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot use function names, as the data will be received as JSON, and controllers are declared using "string" syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it controllers name, not string:

```
function ComponentsController($scope) {
    $scope.components = [{
        name: "Wd1",
        controller: Ctrl1,
    }, {
        name: "Wd2",
        controller: Ctrl2,
    }];

    $scope.test = "test";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot use function names, as the data will be received as JSON, and controllers are declared using "string" syntax.