# Angular 1.4: Add directives dynamically to markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a web application thats written mostly in Jquery, that is essentially a dashboard that a user can add any number of custom widgets to. I have the users currently added widgets, so when its loaded up I masically append each widget to the DOM. I want to work on converting this to an Angular application however im stumbling on one major issue.

1)I can recreate each widget as a directive, that will work nicely. However what I'm struggling with is how to add each widget that a user has setup on load. My first attempt at solving this was to create a generic widget directive, and doing an ng-repeat, and dynamically assigning the widget its controller/templateUrl.

In theory this seems great however I ran into some issues with not being able to dynamically pass the controller name via attribute. if I hard coded a string value it would work, but wouldnt a data-bound attribute in the ng-repeat. Example below does not work.

```
<quidget ng-dynamic-controller="quidget.QuidgetName" ng-repeat="quidget in tab.quidgets track by $index"></quidget>
```

if instead of quidget.QuidgetName I passed in the actual name of the controller, it would work...like so

```
<quidget ng-dynamic-controller="quidget1Controller" ng-repeat="quidget in tab.quidgets track by $index"></quidget>
```

Does anyone have any insight on how I can go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic controllers bound from scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775251/dynamic-controllers-bound-from-scope)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the controller name dynamically to the directive you can define the name of the controller in the template of that widget (this is assuming that every widget has a different template). For example you just pass the widget name to the controller:

```
<quidget ng-repeat="quidget in quidgets" name="quidget.name">
```

Next, in your quidget directive's template you conditionally load the template based on the name of the widget, some thing like this:

```
<div  ng-switch on="name">

    <div ng-switch-when="widget1" >
        <ng-include src="'widget1.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="widget2" >
        <ng-include src="'widget2.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>

</div>
```

and inside each widget's template you define the Controller name like this:

```
<p ng-controller="widget1Ctrl">This is widget1.</p>
```

Here is a working plunker that illustrates the whole idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/dBqHRqChy17U8pFI9PXH

I know it's kind of a messy solution and I am pretty sure this can be accomplished in a much simpler manner.